# How solve equation:$y^4+4y^2x-11y^2+4xy-8y+8x^2-40x+52=0$

Tags: calculus

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, solve this follow equation:$$y^4+4y^2x-11y^2+4xy-8y+8x^2-40x+52=0$$

My try: Since 
$$8x^2+4x(y^2+y-10)+y^4-11y^2-8y+52=0$$

then I can't. Maybe this problem have other nice methods.Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$8x^2+x\left( 4y^2+4y-40\right) +y^4-11y^2-8y+52=0$$

This is quadratic in $x$, thus

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-4y^2-4y+40\pm \sqrt{\left( 4y^2+4y-40\right)^2-32\left( y^4-11y^2-8y+52\right)}}{16}$$

Now, use

$$\left( 4y^2+4y-40\right)^2-32\left( y^4-11y^2-8y+52\right)=-16(y-2)^2(y+1)^2$$

to show that the equation has solutions if and only if $y \in \{-1,2\}$.

Comment: It's nice! Thank you +1

Comment: Agreed.Nice idea!.

Answer (score 1):

For another approach, you can rotate the axes, so that your $xy-$ terms disappear, and you're left with a conic section , i.e., a parabola, ellipse, hyperbola, etc. for which solutions are easy to find. Then go back over your change of axes to get a solution for the original.

The idea is to rotate the plane in such a way to make the $xy-$ terms disappear. The actual transformation is given by $$x=rcos\theta-rsin\theta$$ , and $$y=rsin\theta+rcos\theta$$

You substitute in your equation, and the you set the coefficients of mixed-terms equal to zero. This will give you the angle of rotation. Let me give you a link to a simple example:

http://www.mathamazement.com/Lessons/Pre-Calculus/09_Conic-Sections-and-Analytic-Geometry/rotation-of-axes.html

Comment: Can I ask how do you go about doing this change of axes?

Comment: Sure; give me a few minutes, please.

Comment: @Sebastian: what level of detail do you want? I'm writing the basic idea. Please let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: A general idea of how change of axes works is enough, I can work the details on my own! Thanks!

Comment: Does the lay out I just edited work for you?

Comment: Oh yeah! basically just rotation from linear algebra (I tend to forget those details).